# Slice Pandas DataFrame to show all records of a particular day

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I want to return a dataframe that contains only the records of a particular day given a datetime value.

Code below is working:

```
def dataframeByDay(datetimeValue):
    cYear = datetimeValue.year
    cMonth = datetimeValue.month
    cDay = datetimeValue.day
    crit = (df.index.year == cYear) & (df.index.month == cMonth) & (df.index.day == cDay)
    return df.loc[crit]
```

Is there a better (faster) way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the index is a `DatetimeIndex` you can use strings to slice it.

Consider the dataframe `df`

```
np.random.seed([3,1415])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(10, 3)),
                  pd.date_range('2016-03-31', periods=10, freq='12H'),
                  list('ABC'))

df

                     A  B  C
2016-03-31 00:00:00  0  2  7
2016-03-31 12:00:00  3  8  7
2016-04-01 00:00:00  0  6  8
2016-04-01 12:00:00  6  0  2
2016-04-02 00:00:00  0  4  9
2016-04-02 12:00:00  7  3  2
2016-04-03 00:00:00  4  3  3
2016-04-03 12:00:00  6  7  7
2016-04-04 00:00:00  4  5  3
2016-04-04 12:00:00  7  5  9
```

**Not What You Want**
You don't want to use the `Timestamp`

```
df.loc[pd.to_datetime('2016-04-01')]

A    0
B    6
C    8
Name: 2016-04-01 00:00:00, dtype: int64
```

**Instead**
You can use this technique:

```
df.loc['{:%Y-%m-%d}'.format(pd.to_datetime('2016-04-01'))]

                     A  B  C
2016-04-01 00:00:00  7  3  1
2016-04-01 12:00:00  0  6  6
```

**Your Function**

```
def dataframeByDay(datetimeValue):
    return df.loc['{:%Y-%m-%d}'.format(datetimeValue)]

dataframeByDay(pd.to_datetime('2016-04-01'))

                     A  B  C
2016-04-01 00:00:00  7  3  1
2016-04-01 12:00:00  0  6  6
```

---

Here are some alternative approaches

```
def dataframeByDay2(datetimeValue):
    dtype = 'datetime64[D]'
    d = np.array('{:%Y-%m-%d}'.format(datetimeValue), dtype)
    return df[df.index.values.astype(dtype) == d]

def dataframeByDay3(datetimeValue):
    return df[df.index.floor('D') == datetimeValue.floor('D')]
```

Comment: first of all, thank you very much for the answer. I get blissed by all the support I get here on the internet. 
I just wanted to update you that my code ran a lot faster (~2 seconds) than the code you updated here (~8 seconds) and to check if you have another suggestion on how to implement it.

Comment: I updated my post with some alternative approaches.  However, I tested the code with an dataframe 10,000 rows long and my approach was an order of magnitude faster.  If you are seeing the results you claim, there must be something distinct about what you're running that makes it that way.